# Disney+ suddenly doesn't work in Brave on Linux, but it does on Windows

Tags: chrome, video

Disney+ suddenly doesn't work in Brave (Chromium-based) on Linux, but it does on Windows

It won't play a movie or series, the main page works, just everything but actual playback.

The page is in one color, if refreshed (Ctrl+F5) it becomes black. Nothings's in it.

Tried removing all relevant cookies; Tried updating Brave; Tried starting Brave from terminal with no relevant messages while playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disney+ [recently changed the user agent rules](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/11/its-not-just-you-disney-doesnt-currently-work-on-linux) in their analytics, which means that it no longer works on Linux. To fix that, change your user agent; one reported working setting is “Firefox 83 on Windows”.